# PHP returns line not capture in tested regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a file like:

I'm trying to capture the second column on the line that starts with 2341 with a PHP script on a linux box.

```
2341    92
2206    100
2594    15
```

However, this is returning the entire line. Why does it not just give me `$1`

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("count.txt");

$file_contents = preg_replace("/2341\t(\d+?)/m", "$1", $file_contents, 1);

echo  $file_contents;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take out `/m` flag that is used for making `^` and `$` match in each line of a multiline string input. Also use `\s+` instead of `\t`:

```
preg_replace("/2341\s+(\d+)/", "$1", $file_contents, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file contains spaces, not tabs, so the regex pattern wouldn't match. Use `\s+` instead (which would match any kind of whitespace characters, including tabs).

```
^2341\s+(\d+)$
```

You're *extracting* something out of a raw text, not really *replacing*, so [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) might be more appropriate for this task. Here's how you can use it with `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match("/^2341\s+(\d+)$/m", $file_contents, $matches);
echo  $matches[1];
```

Comment: But when I do show all characters in Notepad++ I see that it is actually `2341[tab]92CRLF`

Comment: @thomas: Could it be a copy & paste error? I see spaces instead. The regex should work for both anyway. Here's the difference: [with tabs](http://regex101.com/r/oZ0zW9) — [with spaces](http://regex101.com/r/lH7vR4).